# Hyperlink not imported in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to copy PPT slides to another slide with specifying a pre-defined template.  In order to do that, I used `org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet#importContent()`.  However, hyperlink doesn't seem to be copied even if it is contained in a text shape.  It would be appreciated if anybody let me make sure hyperlinks are not maintained before/after `importContent()`?  The Apache POI version is 3.17.

Comment: 3.17 was released in 2017. Could you try a new version of POI?